# Azure - programmatical access to internal endpoints (uris) of role instances in another cloud service within the same virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I have an azure virtual network with several cloud services and would like to establish communications among role instances from different cloud services dynamically.

Within the same cloud service, I was able to retrieve internal endpoints of other role instances by accessing `RoleEnvironment` and search for roles by role names.

I understand that within the same virtual network, vms can communicate via internal endpoints even across cloud services. However, I do not know how to retrieve internal endpoints of role instances located in a different cloud service in the same virtual network dynamically (programmatically). Does `RoleEnvironment` class still works in this case, or are there other classes I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

As your description that the VMs in the same virtual network can commuicate with each other using VM ip.

But we can only retrieve information about role instances in the same cloudservice with Azure Mangaged Library. More info please refer to official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances#using-the-net-sdk-to-access-an-endpoint),

> You can only retrieve information about role instances that are running in your cloud service and that define at least one internal endpoint. You cannot obtain data about role instances running in a different service.

If we need to communicate between separate cloudservice programmatical that we may need to use [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Azure serviceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions).